# Non-blocking ORM for Tornado?

Tags: python, database, orm, tornado

Is there any asynchronous Python ORM other than [Twistar](http://findingscience.com/twistar/)?

I'm looking for lightweight ORM for non-blocking API, built on top of tornado. Of course, I can write raw SQL queries using momoko, but I'd like to work with objects.

Comment: look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/10216120/1321404

Comment: SQLAlchemy + gevent is overkill. Momoko I'm using already. And looking for solution between these two.

Comment: not that I know of, but I'm actually thinking about writing one recently. maybe on top of redis though and not on top of any SQL :)

Comment: That's great, but we need async ORM on top of sql. :)

Comment: @NikolayFominyh did you found any async ORM so far? and, just curios, why Twistar is not suitable for you?

Comment: @Grievoushead I don't use ORM in tornado apps at the moment. Twistar from twisted stack - has a lot of dependencies.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's been 5 years, and a lot changed. We wrote [GINO](https://github.com/fantix/gino) to be a lightweight ORM on top of [asyncpg](https://magicstack.github.io/asyncpg/current/) and [SQLAlchemy core](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_1/#sqlalchemy-core). It is for asyncio and PostgreSQL only. GINO as "GINO Is Not ORM", because it applied almost none usual ORM patterns, in order to be explicit and simple.

Comment: GINO started 1 month ago. I will follow you. If you will keep tempo - in next year we will see good solution to play with tornado.

Comment: One year passed :) @NikolayFominyh

Comment: Ha, atm we are working on the separation of extensions for GINO 1.0. Will be there soon! Also, a lot more great solutions are coming up: tortoise-orm, encode/databases, just to mention a few

Answer (score 15):

Sure, it is! Look at [peewee](https://github.com/coleifer/peewee) and [peewee-async](https://github.com/05bit/peewee-async) extension. Disclaimer: extension is only for PostgreSQL at the moment and I'm an author of extension :)

It's not specifically for Tornado, but Tornado can run on asyncio event loop.

Comment: Thanks, will take a look, when get chance! =)

Answer (score 5):

Have a look at Tortoise [ORM](https://github.com/tortoise/tortoise-orm)

Its aiming to be a full-featured `ORM` inspired by `Django syntax`, but asycnio only.
Since `Tornado 5.0` runs on asyncio, it should just work.

Answer (score 2):

None exist. The only ORM that could even consider coming close to being lightweight is [PeeWee](https://github.com/coleifer/peewee), and that isn't async. ORMs are hard to write, and even harder to write **well**. It needs to have a nice, clean API, expose many features of the underlying DB, *and* be efficient. A tall order!

There aren't many ORMs for Python, and even fewer async ones. Sorry.

Comment: [peewee-async](https://github.com/05bit/peewee-async) is a wrapper for peewee ORM for async interface, just mentioned it [above](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26663553/326406).

Comment: Awesome! Great to see one finally come up :)

Answer (score 1):

If using mongo you can look into Asyncmongo (not an orm but let's you access your data Async)
https://github.com/bitly/asyncmongo

if it is of interest see video and slides from this webminar: "Asynchronous MongoDB with Python and Tornado" http://www.10gen.com/presentations/webinar/Asynchronous-MongoDB-with-Python-and-Tornado

Comment: Sorry, but question about ORM. I know, that we can access sql and nosql storages in async way.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to have a look at [Monguo](https://github.com/shiyanhui/monguo), a "full-featured, asynchronous MongoDB ORM with Motor driver for Tornado applications" as it describes itself.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to have a look at umysqldb(https://github.com/hongqn/umysqldb), A MySQLdb compatible wrapper around ultramysql. ultramysql compatible with gevent through monkey patching.