# Is there easy way to change from sync to async way of fetching results from database in Tornado?

Tags: python, python-2.7, tornado

At the moment I don't have async code. My Tornado cost looks like

```
class EmployeeHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    '''Returns all users which satisfy conditions'''

    def post(self):
        data = tornado.escape.json_decode(self.request.body)
        age = data['age']
        education = data['education']
        result = self._filter(education, age)
        self.write(json.dumps(result))
        self.flush()

    def _filter(self, education, age):
        '''Reads from local database a lot using SQLAlchemy, make joins and is slow'''
        pass
```

Is there easy way to make this async, to fetch result from filter asynchronously?

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10214042/can-sqlalchemy-be-configured-to-be-non-blocking

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to answer this question when we don't see the code in `_filter` function but I'll try to suggest you some directions to research.

First, take a look at python's [generators](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators) and `yield` [keyword](http://www.jeffknupp.com/blog/2013/04/07/improve-your-python-yield-and-generators-explained/).

Second, take a look at tornado's `add_callback` [method](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/ioloop.html?highlight=callback#tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.add_callback), which allows you to use asynchronous approach and even make use of multithreading.